# Do you domesticate a wild animal or do you tame it?

Tags: word-choice

When you want to make a wild animal, let's say a lion, give up some of its natural instincts and be nice to it's potential prey (aka human!), do you "**domesticate**" it or do you "**tame**" it? I couldn't find the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were simply removing the instincts that made the lion a threat, you would say that you tamed it.

[Domesticate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/domesticate) generally means that the lion would then be suitable to keep in the house or in your yard/garden or on your farm.  Domesticating would mean that the lion *had* been tamed but you can also tame a lion *without* domesticating it.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about a single animal, *domesticate* can be used as a synonym for *tame*.

If you are talking about a species though, *domesticate* is used rather than *tame*.

You couldn't use *tame* in place of *domesticate* here:

> Cattle were domesticated about ten thousand years ago.